# Drupal custom OG subscribe url

Tags: organic-groups

I am using latest version of Organic Groups module. And create a page with panel page to view this group (classroom) content type. After that I added group_group field to subscribe user in this node.

But when user is going to subscribe, this path look like:

siteURL/group/node/63/subscribe/og_user_node

**But I want to customize this path which look like:**

siteURL/classroom/subscribe/?classroomId=63

It's not necessary to make it (siteURL/classroom/subscribe/?classroomId=63)

But I want to remove "group/node" & "og_user_node" from url and replace with other word.

Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest the most easy thing to do: Create a menu item and in that menu item you'll create the membership by your self. Don't know why this happening to you but the solution i suggest might be quicker.

Comment: Dear Roy, actually I did not understand what you really suggest. May be I don't have that much knowledge on drupal. If you write step by step it will so helpful for me. I used panel to view "drupal group node". Thanks a lot.